# How to set a root directory for PyRight?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pyright

I have  a Python project in VSCode. Its structure

```
root
+-- docs
+-- some_other_folder
+-- src
    +-- app
    |   +-- main.py
    +-- tests
        +-- conftest.py
```

`conftest.py` has import

```
from app.main import app
```

My task is to set `src` as root folder because in otherwise I got a warning `Import 'app.main' could not be resolved`

Answer (score 18):

Create `pyrightconfig.json` at the root directory of your project

Add the following config:

```
{
    "executionEnvironments": [
        {"root": "src"}
    ]
}
```

Details taken from: https://github.com/Microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md