# Fix pyrIght warning "Import [module] could not be resolved"?

Tags: python, neovim, pyright, nvim-lspconfig

I have the following `Projects` folder structure:

[image]

and the file `Tasks/Scripts/test.py` (shown below) attaches `util.py` from `Libs/PyLibs`:

[image]

The file `test.py` executes fine without any issue, but I cannot get rid of the import warning (I am using latest neovim with lsp/mason/null-ls plugins). Similar issues were reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60820640/how-to-set-a-root-directory-for-pyright) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59108805/fixing-import-module-could-not-be-resolved-in-pyright), but none of the methods suggested there, for example putting a `pyrightconfig.json` or `pyproject.toml` file in the project root with appropriate [config settings](https://github.com/Microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md), is working for me, maybe because I have a somewhat more complex folder structure.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add `extraPaths` to `pyrightconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extraPaths": ["/home/roy/Projects/Libs/PyLibs/"]
}
```

> extraPaths [array of strings, optional]: Additional search paths that
> will be used when searching for modules imported by files. - [Pyright Main Configuration Options](https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/#/configuration?id=main-configuration-options)